# How to Save an image(jpeg) downloaded by httpclient in windows phone localstorage?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I am looking for any example to save an image downloaded from httpClient into local storage. I know how to save files from local resources to local storage. But did not find any example on how to save image after downloading from uri?

For now I have reached at this point

```
try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
                return;
            var url = new Uri(imageUrl);
            var thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(url);

            var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Constants.Profile_Picture_Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            //How to save RandomAccessStream to file here!
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution

```
 var url = new Uri(httpUrl);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(url.LocalPath);
            if (folder == null)
                folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.Member_Images_Folder, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);    

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

            var imageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(imageFile, bytes);
```